# Vacuum sealing hops

Tags: hops, storage

Is it a good idea to vacuum seal hops for storage using the method described in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NMDfyRjfBbc)?

I Often buy multiple varieties and have partially used packages laying around in my fridge until the next time I'm brewing a style they fit (both pellets and dried whole).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to store hops?](http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/620/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-hops)

Comment: Just to elaborate for anyone not viewing the video - the video shows a glass mason jar, which has some of the air removed via a hand pump. I don't think it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Using mason jars will not be as good as using flexible packaging. Both hand pumps and food savers only create a partial vacuum, so only a percentage of the air is removed. With the mason jar, there will be a greater amount of air left in the jar since it's inflexible and a larger fixed volume compared to plastic/mylar packaging which changes shape and compresses the hops together, reducing space between the hops and between the hops and packaging.

Removing the oxygen helps reduce the rate of oxidization. So I think this technique will work, and work well, just not as well as using a mylar bag.

You will get much better preservation of the hops if you freeze them (with or without a vacuum), rather than storing in the fridge.

Answer (score 0):

I typically use a vacuum sealer to store my hops using technique #1 from [Home Brew Finds](http://www.homebrewfinds.com/2011/08/vacuum-sealing-mylar-bags-foodsaver.html).  Since I typically buy hops in 1 pound bags that are sealed in mylar, this works perfectly.  I've sealed hops like this for up to 18 months with only a little loss of flavor and aroma.